# "Synchronized" transactions for bidding system

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, concurrency, synchronized

I tried to implement a bidding system with the following "naïve" implementation of a BidService, using Grails 2.1 (so Hibernate and Spring)
But it seems to fail to prevent raise conditions and this results in "duplicate" bids from differente concurrent users.

A couple of information:
- BidService is transactional by default,
- Item and Bid model use "version: false" (pessimistic locking)

```
class BidService{
  BidResult processBid(BidRequest bidRequest, Item item) throws BidException {
        // 1. Validation
        validateBid(bidRequest, item)   // -> throws BidException if bidRequest do not comply with bidding rules (price too low, invalid user, ...) 
       // 2. Proces Bid (we have some complex rules to process the bids too, but at the end we only place the bid
       Bid bid = placeBid(bidRequest, item)

       return bid
  }

   Bid placeBid(BidRequest bidRequest, Item item){
      // 1. Place Bid
      Bid bid = new Bid(bidRequest) // create a bid with the bidRequest values
      bid.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

      // 2. Update Item price
      item.price = bid.value
      item.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

      return bid      
   }
}
```

But as stated in http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html  9.2 Scoped Services:
By default, access to service methods is not synchronised, so nothing prevents concurrent execution of those methods. In fact, because the service is a singleton and may be used concurrently, you should be very careful about storing state in a service. Or take the easy (and better) road and never store state in a service.

I thought of using "synchronized" on the whole processBid() method but that sounds rather rude and could raise liveness issues or deadlocks.
On the other hand, processing bids in async way, prevents to send direct user feedback about winning/loosing the auction.

Any advice or best practice to use in this case?

PS: I already asked on the grails ML but it's a rather wide Java concurrency question.

Answer (score 2):

Your service is stateless, so there is no need to synchronize it, synchronization is needed when it comes to state.

Also you don't need to use any locking since again.. you don't change the existing state, you only add new rows. Moreover, I'm not a GORM expert, but `version: false` should switch off optimistic locking from what its name says, and this doesn't mean pessimistic locking is activated.

From your question I don't understand what is your problem, but unique constraints is what preventing duplication in database.

Comment: The validation steps takes some time and involve state: item's current price, other bids, dynamic bids, ...
So if it happens to have 2 simultaneous validation (going right) placing the bid for both of the user, will result in a duplicate bid value. I will look in the unique approach which seems the better even if it implies to change some logic when dealing with dynamic bids.
You're probably be right about version:false I will check the doc.

Comment: version:false turns off optimistic locking, but to use pessimistic locking you need an explicit call item.lock() http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking
I will test again but it's probably wiser to go for unique constraints